# Winmerge - Way to make identical lines not to be shown when compare 2 files?

Tags: file, comparison, winmerge

When I compare 2 large files
I used `winmerge`
It is a great tool that can find the delta between 2 files

In my case
*Each of 2 files nearly contains 3000 lines*
And there are some lines ONLY contain changes

Any Way to make identical lines in both files not to be shown when compare?
And **show ONLY lines that have deltas**?

To can inspect only DELTA lines and minimize scrolling overhead hover too long vertical files comparison result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: [My answer is not correct anymore. See answer blow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56599126/4136669)

OLD ANSER:

From the [winmerge FAQ:](http://manual.winmerge.org/Faq.html)

4.6. Can I hide similar lines in a file comparison, so that only different lines are visible?

> No, you can't. Many users have requested this feature but we don't
> have any plans to implement it. We don't believe it would really
> improve usability.

Comment: It's amazing to me that developers could be so oblivious to the needs of their userbase that they believe that a feature **requested by many users** would *not* improve usability.

Comment: Thanks, so we can move between changes using buttons `ALT` + `UP` or `DOWN`

Comment: Actually this is outdated, currently as Alin Oltean responded it is now available.  This answer should be unmarked, and corrected to the one for Alin Oltean

Comment: As of 2022 you can indeed just go to "View > Diff Context" and select "0 lines". This answer should be edited/removed.

Answer (score 38):

In version 2.16 you can go to menu View - Diff Context and select 0 lines. This will only make visible the different lines in 2 files, and hide the rest.

Comment: This is now the correct answer. This seems to be default behaviour in a new installed Winmerge, what confused the hell out of me... where are the identical lines??? But now I know how to configure winmerge back to the old behaviour, Thanks!

Comment: With `CTRL-D` you can toggle between all lines and your selection of 0-9 lines